# How to pull a List of objects from FormDataCollection

Tags: c#, api

I'm calling my API via a post. I am trying to get the values out from the `FormDataCollection`, but I cannot figure out how to get the list called `ResourcesInfo`?

---

UPDATE:

Here are the raw values:

### [image]

Here is my setup:

What am I doing wrong here?

```
          var resourceInfo2 = form.Get("ResourcesInfo");
            var resourceInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<SchedulerConflictResourceInfoModel>>(form.Get("ResourcesInfo"));
```

```
namespace WebPortal.MVC.Areas.Scheduler.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    /// <summary>
    /// Scheduler conflict param model
    /// Obtain the values after the start or end date changes to check for conflicts
    /// </summary>
    public class SchedulerConflictParamModel
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the start date.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>
        /// The start date.
        /// </value>
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the end date.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>
        /// The end date.
        /// </value>
        public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the resources information.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>
        /// The resources information.
        /// </value>
        public IList<SchedulerConflictResourceInfoModel> ResourcesInfo { get; set; }
    }
}
```

```
namespace WebPortal.MVC.Areas.Scheduler.Models
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Scheduler conflict resource info model
    /// Holds the resource type id and resource id to check for conflicts
    /// </summary>
    public class SchedulerConflictResourceInfoModel
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the resource type identifier.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>
        /// The resource type identifier.
        /// </value>
        public int ResourceTypeId { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the resource identifier.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>
        /// The resource identifier.
        /// </value>
        public int ResourceId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

```
function schedulerCheckForConflicts2(model) {
    var deferred = $.Deferred()

    let apiUrl = BuildSafeURL("api/SchedulerData/SchedulerCheckForConflicts", null)

    $.post(apiUrl, {
        StartDate: model.StartDate,
        EndDate: model.EndDate,
        ResourcesInfo: model.ResourcesInfo
    })
    .done(function (conflicts) {
        DevExpress.ui.notify("called server... ", "warning", 1200)
        deferred.resolve(conflicts)
    })
    .fail(function (error) {
        genericErrorMessage()
        console.log("error⚠️", error)
    })

    return deferred.promise();
}
```

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the items scheduler file manager.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="form">The form.</param>
        /// <returns>File system items</returns>
        [HttpPost]
        [WebAPIValidateAntiForgeryToken]
#pragma warning disable CS1998 // Async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously
        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SchedulerCheckForConflicts(FormDataCollection form)
#pragma warning restore CS1998 // Async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously
        {
            var startDate = form.Get("StartDate");
            var endDate = form.Get("EndDate");
            var resourceInfo2 = form.Get("ResourcesInfo");
            var resourceInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<SchedulerConflictResourceInfoModel>>(form.Get("ResourcesInfo"));

            var schedulerConflictParamModel = new SchedulerConflictParamModel();

            return Request.CreateResponse(new List<int>
            {
                1, 2, 3
            });
        }
```

Comment: Can you show the raw string value that gets send to your Action.  What's inside `form.Get("ResourcesInfo")`?

Comment: Charles: I added a screen shot. I think that is what you are looking for?

Comment: I think only the model binder can parse those values. Try to use the model directly as a parameter for the action `SchedulerCheckForConflicts(SchedulerConflictParamModel incData)`

Comment: You can also try to add another param to the action like:
`SchedulerCheckForConflicts([ModelBinder(Name = "ResourcesInfo")] 
IList<SchedulerConflictResourceInfoModel> incData2)`. Maybe you can also invoke the ModelBinder manually.